# Is it feasible to create computer-like hardware designed to execute a specific algorithm?

Tags: fpga, programming, cpu

Computers take a set of instructions, and execute them sequentially really really fast.

The number of sets of instructions they could be given is vast.  However my rudimentary understanding of processors and FPGA's makes me wonder if...

1.) many algorithms could be implemented at a hardware level?
2.) these implementations would run those algorithms, dollar for dollar, faster than CPU?

If this is possible, why is it not being done and what are the barriers?

Comment: Yes it is possible, and yes it is being done. Useful search term "reconfigurable computing".

Comment: Special-purpose hardware algorithm implementations are very common. The key factor is the **dollar for dollar** comparison. It is only when the market is large enough to justify the engineering design expense that a custom chip is manufactured. A very common example would be an MP3 decoder in a cheap media player.

Comment: Answer is yes.  That's what many/most FPGA designs do - they execute a single, or multiple algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, many algorithms are faster when executed in hardware than in software.
2. Yes, hardware is faster, because it runs on hardware, not software. However, high end FPGAs are expensive, and custom ASICs are expensive as well. Sometimes it is just cheaper to execute something in software, and it will be cheaper as it does not need dedicated hardware. It all depends on how much you want to pay for making it faster and execute in hardware.

It is done. People buy dedicated hardware for specific tasks, reconfigurable or not. There are CPU chips, there are GPU chips, there are DSP chips, there are video processor chips, audio processor chips, even crypto currency mining chips. FPGA is just a logic chip that can be reconfigured for certain task, and developing a hard-copy to a implement a specific function as an ASIC chip.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the compression and un-compression of images on smart_phones.

Using just the right collection of gates/read_only_memories, lets the movies be compressed into FLASH read-write memory in realtime.

Paul Gray of UCBerkeley spoke of his PhD students  "A motivated PhD candidate can implement almost any algorithm, to run at 100MHz while consuming only 1 milliWatt."

Human ingenuity.